# Python 3 while True: loop

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, python-3.4

I am struggling to implement a `while True:` loop in my code.

At the point of `if file_removed in bs:` I need to ask the user for a new `int` from the list of links provided (go back to `which_link = input(lb + "\n|Which vodlocker link should we use?\n|\n| --> ")`) if `file_removed` is present on the page.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from GoogleScraper import scrape_with_config, GoogleSearchError
from urllib.request import urlretrieve
from urllib.request import URLError
from urllib.request import urlopen
from hurry.filesize import size
from sys import getsizeof
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
import subprocess as sp
import requests as r
import pandas as pd
from pyprind import ProgBar
import psutil
import string
import tqdm
import time
import sys
import re
import os    

def the_link():
    lb = "+--------------------------------------------------------------+"
    site = "site:vodlocker.com " # prefix of search term
    keywords = site + input(lb + "\n|Film to search\n|\n| --> ") # ask user for search term
    config = {
    'use_own_ip': True,
    'keyword': keywords,
    'search_engines': ['google'],           # various configuration settings
    'num_pages_for_keyword': 1,
    'scrape_method': 'http',
    #'sel_browser': 'phantomjs',            # this makes scraping with browsers headless and quite fast.
    'do_caching': True,
    'num_results_per_page': 50,
    'log_level': 'CRITICAL',
    'output_filename': 'results.csv'        # file to save links to 
    }
    try:
        search = scrape_with_config(config)
    except GoogleSearchError as e:
        print(e)
    csv_file = "results.csv" # create an instance of the file
    df = pd.read_csv(csv_file) # read said file
    vodlocker_link = df['link'] # get the vodlocker links from the file (note: you can also use df.column_name
    link_id = df['title']
    results = df['num_results_for_query']
    results_lower = results[0].lower()
    print(lb + "\nWe have found " + results_lower + "\n") # print the link we will use
    title_dict = [
    "HDTV","hdtv", "BDRip","BRrip", "HDRip", "HDTS", "hdts",  # disc type
    "720p", "1080p",                                          # dimensions
    "XviD", "Watch",
    "mp4", "MP4", "X264",                      
    "mkv", "MKV",                                             # video types
    "avi", "AVI", 
    "-LOL", "LOL",
    "ac3", "AC3",
    "-playnow", "playnow", "VoDLocker", "-", "_"
    "AC3-PLAYNOW",
    "EVO", "evo",
    "GECKOS", "FASTSUB",                                      # tags 
    "DIMENSION", "-DIMENSION",
    "REPACK", "Vostfr",
    "VOSTFR", "libre",
    "fum", "-fum",
    "on 4vid tv online", "(", ")"
    ]
    regex_title = r"|".join(title_dict)
    print(link_id)
    s = r.Session() # create an instance of a requests session
    headers = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 7_1_2 like Mac OS X) Safari/9537.53", "Accept":"text/q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8", "Accept-Language":"en-US,en"} # set the user agent and stuff in the header 
    which_link = input(lb + "\n|Which vodlocker link should we use?\n|\n| --> ")
    req = s.get(vodlocker_link[int(which_link)], headers=headers) # get the page from link
    bs = BS(req.text, "lxml") # create a soup object
    file_removed = "<h3>The file was removed by administrator</h3>"
    if file_removed in bs:
        print("The file was removed by administrator")
    else:
        film = bs.find(type="video/mp4") # find the film link
        film_link = film["src"] # get the actual film link
        title = bs.find(id="file_title").get_text()
        fixed_title = re.sub(regex_title, "",title, flags=re.I)
        title_lower = fixed_title.lower()
        title_strip = title_lower.strip()
        title_hyphen = title_strip.replace(" ", "-")
        print(lb + "\n|The title of the film is:\n|" + fixed_title)
        print(lb + "\n|We found a video link on the vodlocker page:\n|" + film_link)
        prfx = "/home/jack/server.files/mp4/films/" # prefix for file_name location
    #    file_name = input("Please name the file:\n--> ") # ask user for file name
        ext = film_link[-4:]
        file_name = title_hyphen + ext
        print(lb + "\n|We will name the file:\n|\n|" + file_name)
        file_name_ok = input(lb + "\n|We have attempted to name the file from the title. Is our guess O.K?\n|\n|[Any key to cotinue]--> ") #TODO prompt user for name if we cant guess it
        u = s.get(film_link, headers=headers, stream=True) # create an instance of the file stream
        file_size = int(u.headers["content-length"]) # get meta info -- file size
        print(lb + "\n|File Path and name:\n|\n|" + prfx + file_name) # print the file name and path
        print(lb + "\n|File Size: " + size(file_size)) # print the file size
        bar = ProgBar(file_size / 1024, title=lb + "\n|Downloading:\n|\n|" + file_name + "\n" + lb, stream=sys.stdout, bar_char='█', update_interval=1)
        with open(prfx + file_name, 'wb') as f:
            dl = 0
            if file_size is None: # no content length header
                f.write(r.content) #TODO print error if size is none!
            else:
                for chunk in u.iter_content(1024):
                    dl += len(chunk)
                    f.write(chunk)
                    f.flush()
                    bar.update(item_id = file_name)
        print(lb)
        print("\n|Finished downloading " + file_name)
        print(lb)

the_link()
```

I know my code is messy and in need of formatting nicely so any pointers on that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Put the part that needs to be repeated into a loop. When you reach a successful exit condition, `break` out of the loop:

```
...
headers = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 7_1_2 like Mac OS X) Safari/9537.53", "Accept":"text/q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8", "Accept-Language":"en-US,en"} # set the user agent and stuff in the header 
while True:
    which_link = input(lb + "\n|Which vodlocker link should we use?\n|\n| --> ")
    req = s.get(vodlocker_link[int(which_link)], headers=headers) # get the page from link
    bs = BS(req.text, "lxml") # create a soup object
    file_removed = "<h3>The file was removed by administrator</h3>"
    if file_removed in bs:
        print("The file was removed by administrator")
    else:
        break
film = bs.find(type="video/mp4") # find the film link
film_link = film["src"] # get the actual film link
...
```

Comment: although this should work it sadly doesn't, I'm getting a TypeError `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "basic.py", line 106, in <module>
    the_link()
  File "basic.py", line 71, in the_link
    film_link = film["src"] # get the actual film link
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable`, any ideas? which is the same error I got when `<h3>The file was removed by administrator</h3>` was in fact `in bs:` befotre thadding the `while True` loop.

Comment: The type of `'video/mp4'` wasn't found, so `film` is `None`.

Comment: The type of `'video/mp4'` wouldn't be found because we landed on a page that contains `file_removed = "<h3>The file was removed by administrator</h3>"` but our new `while True` loop was supposed to take care of this exact issue..

Comment: Then that line is a poor indicator of whether the file is ready for parsing. Double-check that that line is actually present in files that should be skipped.

Comment: Your right .. my tired brain isn't functioning well, I changed `file_removed = ".mp4" if file_removed not in bs:` and it works, thanks TIger

Comment: I'm wrong.. it is now stuck in the loop, `while True: which_link = input(lb + "\n|Which vodlocker link should we use?\n|\n| --> ") req = s.get(vodlocker_link[int(which_link)], headers=headers) bs = BS(req.text, "lxml") file_removed = ".mp4"  if file_removed not in bs: print("|We could not find a video file.") else: break film = bs.find(type="video/mp4")` even though .mp4 appears many times.